# I have this Array ( [0] => 36 ) random numbers from 28 to 58; the i need to get that row['36'] and echo it out

Tags: php, arrays

I can't figure out how to get the numbers from the array and get the values from my database form the specific row.

```
<?php

$antal_sections_to_pull = "3";
$min = "28";
$max = "58";

$length  = rand(1,$antal_sections_to_pull);  

echo "<br>";
$a = range($min,$max);   
shuffle($a);    
$array = array_slice($a, 0, $length);
print_r($array);
```

The array gives me this:

> ```
> Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 28 [2] => 58 )
> ```

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM indhold WHERE uid='$artid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
    echo $row[THE ARRAY NUMBER];
};
```

I want to get the value form the row's number from the arrays. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried before? Also can you update your question with proper grammar, and version of software you are running? As of now this question is hard to understand. Please check out this [helpful document on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry but i have truble writing English. Php version 5.5 i think.

Comment: If you print your $row using print_r($row); you might be able to see more information about what $row contains.

Comment: How can i get the array in to $sql = "SELECT ( array ) FROM indhold WHERE uid='$artid'";

Comment: @PMHKD Chances are the keys in your array aren't numbered, they are probably labeled the same as the headers in the database. If you print out $row instead of trying to echo out something from the row then it should become obvious what the keys actually are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode` to format them for `SELECT`

```
$columns = "('".implode("','",$array)."')";
```

SQL Query

```
$sql = "SELECT $columns FROM indhold WHERE uid='$artid'";
```